# A Sony Pro camera's spec shows it shots in 29.97fps, does it really mean it?

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate

According to this [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Video-rate), it seems one of the 'native' frame rate for `ffmpeg` is

> 'ntsc':   30000/1001

while 30000/1001=29.9700... does not equal to 29.97, I wonder if a Sony Pro camera really means it shots in 29.97, not 30000/1001?

If that Sony camera does shot in exact 29.97fps, I suppose we should keep the 29.97fps, should not change the fps of the video file to 30000/1001?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`29.97` is shorthand for 30000/1001. There is no `29.970000...` frame rate standard. FFmpeg will keep the native framerate (usually), so no need to specify an output `-r` value.

Comment: Thanks! So I can understand that the Sony Pro camera, in fact, shot at 30000/1001 fps.